# How to disable screen shots keys from Mac Application

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

I am working on a Mac application where I want to disable screen shot keys when my application is running. Can anyone tell me how to disable screen shot keys (Command+Shift+3 and Command+Shift+4) ?

Comment: You probably don't want to do this unless you really want to seriously annoy your users - don't mess with any functionality that is outside the purview of your app, i.e. system level stuff such as this.

Comment: @PaulR: As I recall, Apple's DVD Player takes steps to make it difficult to take a screen shot of what it's playing, presumably on the theory that it may be copyrighted content.  But I agree that it's annoying to users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I prevent a user from taking screenshots in a Mac application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239685/can-i-prevent-a-user-from-taking-screenshots-in-a-mac-application)