# Can I avoid users take screenshots or video recordings in a Mac application?

Tags: macos, screenshot, video-capture, nswindow, video-recording

I need to protect content in my app in MacOS. I would like this protection involves both taking screenshoots and recording video from it.
I have read several reports here and Apple support but in fact I am only able to avoid taking screeshoot by setting **CGWindowSharingType** feature to none (**kCGWindowSharingNone**) in every NSWindows of my application (with *[NSWindow setSharingType:]* function).

I have read too these reports ([Can I prevent a user from taking screenshots in a Mac application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239685/can-i-prevent-a-user-from-taking-screenshots-in-a-mac-application) and https://github.com/heardrwt/RHAdditions/blob/master/RHAdditions/NSWindow%2BRHPreventCaptureAdditions.m) and I have tested them.
I have had two troubles: 
First, I am only able to avoid making recording from main window of my application, not for all windows (I dont know why..). 
Finally, this method doesnt use "official APIs", then I can not trust this funtionality could be changed without any notification or even it can depend from MacOS version where my app will be run..

It would be **enought** for me to detect if my app (or screen) is being recorded, for freezing content, althought it would be great if anybody tell me if there is any public official API to do this. I have read that you can attach to a notification event in iOS ([How to disable screen Recording in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880491/how-to-disable-screen-recording-in-ios-app)) but i am not able to find a similar functionality in MacOS..

Can anybody tell me if this is possible to do or if Apple doesnt allow this feature specifically ?

Thank you very much

Comment: i am also facing similar issue! Have you found any solution

Comment: Not yet, sorry :(
I only have information that I have describe on previous message.